# UITableView - IndexPath always returns 0 first & takes 2 clicks to pass correct data to view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that segues to a `ViewController`. My tableview contains a list of location names and when you select a location, it passes more detailed data to the view controller about the selected location. My issue is that my index path always returns 0 on the first click / load no matter which row I click. I have to click each row twice for it pass the right data.

**Example:** I click row2 > returns row1's (0) data. I then click row2 again > correctly returns row2's data > I then click row3 > returns row2's data > I have to click row3 again to get row3's data. `indexPathSelected` in the below code is always `0` on load.

```
NSInteger indexPathSelected;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    indexPathSelected = indexPath.row;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showLocationDetails"])

    {
        LocationDetailsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.location = _locationsArray [indexPathSelected];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that prepareForSegue is called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath. When using segues, it's not usually necessary to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all. The sender argument in prepareForSegue:sender: is the cell you selected,, so you can get the index path from it:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showLocationDetails"])

    {
        LocationDetailsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        indexPathSelected = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        vc.location = _locationsArray[indexPathSelected];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`prepareForSegue:sender:` is probably being called before `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, so the first load is initializing `indexPathSelected` with 0 as a default, then passing the previous value each time.

I'd get rid of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and change `prepareForSegue:sender:` as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showLocationDetails"])

    {
        LocationDetailsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath selectedIndexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
        vc.location = _locationsArray[[selectedIndexPath row]];
    }
}
```

It should accomplish the same thing you wanted.