# PrepareForSegue always returns cell at index 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

So this issue is similar to the one described here [UITableView - IndexPath always returns 0 first & takes 2 clicks to pass correct data to view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014252/uitableview-indexpath-always-returns-0-first-takes-2-clicks-to-pass-correct) however the answer they suggested does not help to fix the problem so I'm asking specifically with my code. This is my prepareForSegue method:

```
//send to a detail version of each of the chatters allowing a report a user 
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushToDetail"]){

    ChatterDetailViewController *chatterDetail = [segue destinationViewController];

     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;

    long indexPathSelected = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row;

   Chatter *detailChatter = [_arrayWithoutME objectAtIndex:indexPathSelected];

    NSData *fbImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: detailChatter.url]];

    _detailProfile = [UIImage imageWithData:fbImageData];

   chatterDetail.detailProfile = _detailProfile;
 }
 }
```

Which obviously looks different from the answer suggested on the other question, however I tried that and it did not change anything. Whenever I click on a tableView cell it completes the segue and I see the the profile picture from the first cell (index 0) and not the cell where it was clicked. I tried using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

however it didn't pass the image value like I needed and also when I tried to return using an unwind segue it said the navigation tree was corrupted (doesn't happen with the current code). Basically I can't seem to find why selecting any cell returns only the first cell's information.

EDIT:

here is some code from Chatter Detail's view did load method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
   _detailProfilePicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   _detailProfilePicture.image = _detailProfile;
   [_detailProfilePicture sizeToFit];

 }
```

Again, it does return a picture, however it is only the picture from cell at index 0.

Comment: What does a log of sender give you?

Comment: From the sender I get a <UItableViewCell: id; frame = (0 60; 320 60); text= correct cell text, autoresize= W; layer = <CALayer: id>> which is the correct cell's info

Comment: I misread your last line, it's ok, you are passing the image, so I deleted my second comment.  So, if you log indexPathSelected, is it always 0 no matter what cell you click on? Are you implementing didSelectRowAtIndexPath or not?

Comment: I'm not currently, I tried that before. What happened was like the what happened in the link I posted with my question. It would return the correct image for the cell that I clicked only after I had clicked on a different cell (click on index 1, get null, click on  index 2 get image from index 1). When I tried to directly segue from that it crashed and said I corrupted the navigation tree.

Comment: What is `arrayWithoutME` and how is it initialized?

Comment: In order to maintain the chat room graphics I had to differentiate between incoming users and outgoing users, this tableview represents a  group that does not include oneself, like not counting yourself when in a room of people your talking to. It is a mutable array created by filtering out the user from a JSON, it is created in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: in other words, for [jsonOfUsers count] if object.id = user.id, don't add, or if it doesn't, add to arrayWithoutMe.

Comment: it works fine to populate the tableview with the correct images and text.

Comment: So, you need to do some logging to narrow down the problem. Does a log of indexPathSelected always give you 0 no matter which row you click on? If not does a log of _detailProfile give you a different image when you click on different rows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to extract the indexPath for your selected row in a UITableView:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushToDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    // section and row return an int like this:
    NSLog(@"index path: section %i, row %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);

}
}
```

However, your code does give the correct row value as long, and a long can indeed be used to get an object from an NSArray. I would put a breakpoint or log message at the end of this method and see if the correct value is actually in your array.

I would also check what value you get in your indexPathSelected - this should reflect the selected row.

Comment: I get 0 for indexPathSelected. I tried this method, however it still returned 0.

Comment: Does self.tableView actually reference the table view that's on screen? Quick check to test: NSLog(@"Number of rows in self.tableView: %i", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);

Comment: I get 0, which means I'm not actually referencing what I thought I was I suppose

Comment: So, I connected the tableview to and it does indeed say I have 9 rows with that test, however, when I click on one using indexPathForSelectedRow it returns only 0

Comment: How about indexPath.row?

Comment: it returns 0, so it's like i'm only clicking on the first row.

Comment: However when I put in a tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath I get the correct view. I don't know why there would be a difference in these values.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I'm afraid I'm at my wit's end here. Sorry! I suggest to examine the master/detail template closely and see where your app differs.